# Read S3 Object and write into InMemory Buffer

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to read from S3 and writing into InMemory buffer like:

```
  def inMemoryDownload(bucketName: String, key: String): String = {
  val s3Object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key))
  val s3Stream = s3Object.getObjectContent()
  val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](10* 1024)
  var bytesRead:Int =s3Stream.read(buffer)
  while (bytesRead > -1) {
    info("writing.......")
    outputStream.write(buffer)
    info("reading.......")
    bytesRead = ss3Stream.read(buffer)
  }
  val data = new String(outputStream.toByteArray)
  outputStream.close()
  s3Object.getObjectContent.close()
  data
}
```

But It is giving me heap space error(Size of file on S3 is 4MB)

Comment: You may need to check the heap memory. Also, it is not recommended to have 4mb data in heap memory.

Comment: My JVM heap size is 1G.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using thbytes you just read, when writing into the stream. The way you have it written, writes the entire buffer every time. I doubt that is the cause of your memory problem, but it could be. Imagine that `read` returns a single byte to you every time, and you write 10K into the stream. That's 40G, right there.

Another problem is, that, I am not 100% sure, but I suspect, that  `getObjectObject` creates a new input stream every time. Basically, you just keep reading the same bytes over and over again in the loop. You should put it into a variable instead.

Also, if I may make a suggestion, try rewriting your code in actual scala, not just syntactically, but idiomatically. Avoid mutable state, and use functional transformations. If you are going to write scala code might as well take some time to get into the right mind set. You'll grow to appreciate it eventually, I promise :)

Something like this, perhaps?

```
val input = s3Object.getObjectContent
Stream
  .continually(input.read(buffer))
  .takeWhile(_ > 0)
  .foreach { output.write(buffer, 0, _) }
```

Comment: Thanks. Assigned stream in a variable. but it still not working.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "still not working". The code I wrote above does work.